# SED regular expression error

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am new to `sed` and want to make modifications in `httpd.conf` file.

Here is the text to search

```
  <Directory "/var/www/html">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess    files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None   --- Want to change this to AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
   Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

 </Directory>
```

Task : My task is to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` .

```
  sed 'N;s:<Directory "/var/www/html">\(.*\)AllowOverride None\(.*\):  <Directory "/var/www/html">\1AllowOverride All\2:' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  > newHttpdConf.ini
```

**Explanation of regular expression**

Start with:  `< Directory "/var/www/html">`

store anything till AllowOverride None : `\(.*\)`

Look for : `AllowOverride None`

store anything after that : `\(.*\)`

When I am running above sed command , I am not seeing any replacement. 
What mistake I am making.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex ranges to select a subset of lines and then apply sed commands to them

```
$ sed '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/, /<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' inputFile
```

**What it does?**

- `/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/, /<\/Directory>/` This specifies the line range. That is lines from start match of `/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/` to end match of `/<\/Directory>/`
- `s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/` Does the substitution for all matches of `AllowOverride None` within the range.

Comment: Nice . I am going to try this . Can you please tell me what is the problem with my regular expression it will me not to repeat the same mistake.

Comment: @voila The thing is sed reads line be line and does the pattern matching. So when it reaches line say `<Directory /var/www/html>`, it doesn't know whether `AllowOverride` is gonna occur in lines following. And `.*` will select only till the end of the line and not the next line

Comment: Got it .. Thanks for help